# Combining a variable and part of a control in VBA

Tags: vba, variables, ms-access-2007, subform

I have a subform which could be different depending on a user choice (as they are make table queries).  Consequently I have had to store the actual table name in a variable caled MyResultSO.  This works fine and returns the correct table name.  I am then trying to get the value of a field from the subform.  I am then trying to combine the variable with the field name.text to get the value of the field from the subform but can't get the syntax correct.

I have tried variations but, for example here is one:

```
MyResultSO = Me.RESULTS.SourceObject 
'this works fine and returns "Table.POWER PRICES Query Table 3"

MyProductCode = MyResultSO & !PRODUCT_CODE.Text  
'which is where I am trying to combine the value of variable MyResultSO and the field which is PRODUCT_CODE.Text.
```

Combined this should return the value of the current record from the following:

```
Table.POWER PRICES Query Table 3!PRODUCT_CODE.Text.
```

As you will probably tell from the above, I am not very experienced with VB.

Comment: So you're trying to combine the table name (which you already have) with the actual value from a field located in the subform?

Comment: Your subform is named "Table.POWER PRICES Query Table 3"? It'll be better named as sfrmTablePowerPricesQueryTable3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the private module of the main form, here Me:

```
MyResultSO = Me.RESULTS.SourceObject 

MyProductCode = Me.RESULTS.Form.Controls("PRODUCT_CODE").Value
```

Not to use .Text, that requires .Focus: so is bad, it does not always work!

```
MyProductCode = Me.RESULTS.Form.Controls("PRODUCT_CODE").Text ' <= it's bad.
```

Here PRODUCT_CODE is the name of a control on the subform named "Table.POWER PRICES Query Table 3".

Comment: Thank you so much - that is much easier than I was previously advised to do it.  It works a treat (and I have now changed the name of my subforms) - I know you 'proper' programmers get so irked when us 'novices' apply random names!